# cshtml error when @model.LocationID is null

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

In cshtml, I have a @Model EnrollmentModel.

EnrollmentModel has LocationID field.

When I use the statement below, it works when the locationID exists. However, when the locationID is null, it gives an error.

var params = {LocationID : @Model.LocationID};

When I debug the javascript, it just says var params = {LocationID: };

I need a way for cshtml to convert @Model.LocationID to 0 when the value is null.

I also tried using @Model.LocationID ?? 0, but this converts into {blank} ?? 0 in javascript.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is  to add  a hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" value="@Model.LocationID" id="locationId" />
```

javascript

```
var params = { LocationID : 0};

var locationId=$("#locaionId").val();

if (locationId > 0) params.LocationID = locationId;
....
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. When I tried that it converts the code to
var locationID = 0;
if ( > 0) locationID = ;
var params = { LocationID: locationID };

Comment: @Damon Who converts your code?

Comment: Javascript converted it when I ran the project.

Comment: @Damon I updated my answer